# flutter type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Product>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I got `FutureBuilder` snapshot error when I parsing my JSON i got the:

type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>'
is it my Product model error or a parsing error?

my code

```
 late Future<List<Product>> productFuture = getProducts();

  static Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
    var url = '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=catalog&category_id=$id';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(body['data']);
    return body['data'].map((e)=>Product.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
              future: productFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print(snapshot);
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final catalog = snapshot.data;
                  return buildCatalog(catalog!);
                } else {
                  print('SNAPSOT DATA ${snapshot.data}');
                  return Text("No widget to build");
                }
              }),
```

Comment: can you try `return  List.from(body['data'].map((e)=>Product.fromJson(e)));`

Comment: I thought it has more than this issue , suspected model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [List.from](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/List/List.from.html)

```dart
return List.from(body['data'].map((e)=>Product.fromJson(e)));
```

```dart
static Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
    var url = '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=catalog&category_id=$id';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(body['data']);
    return List.from(body['data'].map((e)=>Product.fromJson(e)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert all `List<Product> --> List<dynamic>`